# How to intercept native network requests in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, networking

I'm using Flutter Devtools to inspect network traffic. Flutter requests made via e.g. the `http` package are indeed tracked, but requests coming from the underneath native iOS and Android apps are not.

Example:

```swift
print("sending request from native iOS.")
let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
  guard let data = data else { return }
  print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
}

task.resume()
```

In the above example, not only that the network request isn't captured, but I can't even see the `print` in Flutter's Android Studio console.

I want to track the native requests and check in e2e tests if they are sent, but currently don't understand why this is not happening by default.